# UITableView with Sections issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have still not fully understood sections in a UITableView, but this is what i got so far:

**My Question** : `How can i figure out how much Data to put in each section?`

Basically, i have JSON data that i parse, then save the data into an NSMutableArray.
Here is the code i use right now to make the two sections:

```
- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0){
        return @"Section 1";
    }
    else{
        return @"Section 2";
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

This works perfectly. It adds two Sections to the TableView. My issue is getting certain data into each section.

Inside the JSON data that a parse, each object has a Date, which i compare to the current date. If the Date is after today, i add it to Section 1. If it is not, then i add it to Section 2.

Here is how i handle that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ... // Date Stuff

    if (indexPath.section== 0 && isNewEvent) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"opponent"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@ | Time: %@", [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"], [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sports.png"];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"opponent"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@ | Time: %@", [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"], [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sports.png"];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

I think this works perfectly, but i get **Duplicated Data** in BOTH sections. I believe that is because of this code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0){
       // return [events count];
    }
    else{
       // return [events count];
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to know how much Data i will put in each section, until this CODE `cellforrowatindexpath` is completed.

If you need any more code, i will be MORE than happy to give it to you. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Sort your events array, get what in the first section, what's in the second, and user [eventsBefore count] and [eventsAfter count].

Comment: Where would i do that? I do all the Data Separating in cellforrowatindexpath`

Comment: @Larme ok, i am doing that now. I have just been looking at this for MANY hours. I needed some fresh eyes on this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all of your processing should be done before the app calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

the flow of your app should be:

In your `viewDidLoad` method you should parse all your data. At this point you should know which objects should go into which section. E.g. maybe have 2 arrays, section one array and second 2 array. Get all your data, loop through it, add the objects to each of the arrays.

Then at this point you can say:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0){
       return [arrayOne count];
    }
    else{
       return [arrayTwo count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try this and get back to you. I guess since i have been looking at this for about 10 Hours, it pays to have someone else take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @EliteGamer There would be many little ways to go about this, if you wanted to expand beyond 2 sections maybe a mutable dictionary where each entry would be a section title and an array of objects. Those little details don't matter right now. The main point of my answer is that the processing HAS to be done in some manner like this in viewDidLoad. The app calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` once per row you have asked for, you should not be doing any processing here for performance reasons as it will be re-run many times. When the app gets to this point, you must have the data ready, simple as that

Comment: thanks so much. And i did not realize that would cause performance issues. I am actually going to add the Data check in the Parser, then have BOTH arrays populated. Thanks for your help. I pays to have a fresh pair of eyes on ones code.